# An inertial degree

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Consider the number field $L=\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt[3]{2}]$. If we let $\alpha=\sqrt[3]{2}+1$, then $(3)=(\alpha)^3$ is a prime decomposition. I think that the inertial degree $f((\alpha)|3)=1$ (am I right?). May I ask what is the fastest way to prove this? Thank you.

Comment: You could observe that $\mathbb F_3(\sqrt[3]2) = \mathbb F_3$. Alternatively, since the ramification index $e$ is clearly $3$, you can use the fact that $ef = [L:\mathbb Q]=3$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The second method I can understand, but not the first. Would you please explain how one can obtain $\mathbb{F}_3(\sqrt[3]{2})=\mathbb{F}_3$? Does $\sqrt[3]{2}\in\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt[3]{2}]/(\alpha)$?

Comment: You can observe that $X^3-2 \equiv (X+1)^3\pmod 3$.

Comment: Okay. I think I now understand more. Thank you very much!

Comment: Also (an alternative way of writing Mathmo123's point): $\root{3}\of2\equiv-1\pmod{\alpha}$, which quickly leads to the conclusion $\Bbb{Z}[\root3\of2]/(\alpha)\simeq\Bbb{Z}_3$.

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen Thank you.